# Div background with radius in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, background-image, css

I have several divs with a 5 degree radius applied to the corners, which also have a background image.

This works fine in Chrome, but I am having problems with them in IE9. Instead of getting the background with rounded corners, I get a white box with a black border...although the corners are rounded.

Please see http://www.thecocktailservice.co.uk/

There are several examples down the page...The h2's near the left edges, the form at the bottom of the page, and the testimonials box half way up.

Any ideas why the backgrounds aren't showing?

Comment: Please post your CSS code. `border-radius` is supposed to work in IE9.

Comment: Yeah, posting your CSS may help

Answer (score 0):

When using chrome to inspect this page, there are several errors and warnings.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
http://www.thecocktailservice.co.uk/demos/images/th-slide-env-1.jpgFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
http://www.thecocktailservice.co.uk/demos/images/th-slide-civil-2.jpgFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
```

These are just some of the few, might want to look into correcting those errors.

In addition, the padding from the line

```
padding:2px 30px 7px 30px;
```

does not seem to be showing up in IE.  Without an area large enough to render the image, IE is probably just leaving the background blank.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the out-dated htc file was messing things up - updated this and it worked fine!